# Create small package combining SO answers?

Tags: discussion, licensing, open-source

I'd like to combine 2-3 existing SO answers (and add an icon and .desktop etc.) to create a small, but useful open-source (Debian) package. I can license everything under "CC-by-SA 3.0", which is the Stackexchange standard license for contributions AFAICT. However how do I go about copyright attribution? Do I have to track down the authors of the answers?

Is this possible or are stackoverflow answers essentially un-reusable in public-facing code? I suppose I could rewrite the code in question, but I don't feel this would be a productive use of anyone's time.

Comment: Link back to their profiles

Comment: I wonder if this is OK for a debian/copyright file... But good ideas